how to show the exception message occurred on a modal for an angular project
every time I upload an invalid file java throws an exception now I want to show the message on the frontend screen when it happens. Note : I am using an angular project.
controller code
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response validateUpload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails,
            @FormDataParam("uploadType") String uploadtype, @FormDataParam("aquiName") String aquiName) {

        logger.debug("Received call to process Auto Account Import template id {}", uploadtype);

        AccountImportType template = AccountImportType.valueOfSafe(uploadtype);
        if (template == null)
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Template not found").build();

        try {
            ImportValidationResult results = importProcessor.doValidation(template, uploadedInputStream);

            return Response.ok().entity(results).build();
        } catch (TemplateNotReadableException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to process upload", e);
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }

these errors in the controller are printing on chrome console I needed them to be on screen so that user is notified.

Phuu there are so many examples and blogs who describe that, when you search in google
